# Background context save causes NSFetchedResultsController didChange anObject to call .delete instead of .update

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using an NSFetchedResultsController in a UICollectionView.

**The problem**: When the user opens the view I send a request to the API and parse the response in the background with `performBackgroundTask()`. The NSFetchedResultsController will load the Managed Objects correctly, but after I parse the data and call `context.save()` the `didChangeObject` method is called with `NSFetchedResultsChangeType.delete` but neither `update` nor `insert` are called after that.

Here's some code.

**Parsing and Saving**

```
static func parse(withJSON json: [JSON]) {
    let container = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer

    container.performBackgroundTask() { (context) in
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        for feedJSON in json {
            if let feedID = feedJSON["_id"].string {
                let feed = Feed.getWithId(id: feedID, withContext: context) ?? (NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Feed", into: context)  as! Feed)
                feed.update(withJSON: feedJSON, withContext: context)
            }
        }

        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failure to save context: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

**View Context**

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {        
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TheApp")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in

        if let error = error as NSError? {                
            #if DEVELOPMENT
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            #endif
        }
    })

    container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy
    container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    container.viewContext.retainsRegisteredObjects = true

    return container
}()
```

**Initializing the NSFetchedResultsController**

```
func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
    guard let user = Current.user else {
        return
    }

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Feed> = Feed.fetchRequest()
    let createdAtSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: false)
    request.sortDescriptors = [createdAtSort]
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "author = %@", user)

    let moc = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    resourceFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    resourceFetchedResultsController?.delegate = self

    do {
        try resourceFetchedResultsController?.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
}
```

`author` is a to-one relationship to a `User` managed object. I've verified that this isn't somehow being deleted when the background context is saved. I've also changed the Delete Rule for the Feed.author relationship to `No Action`, `Nullify`, and `Cascade` with no change.

**Object Change Notifications**

Finally, I've set notifications to listen to changes in the context. It is successfully called after every `context.save()` in the `performBackgroundTask()`, but it only ever has information on the object being updated, and never deleted.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextWillSave, object: nil)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(managedObjectContextObjectsDidChange), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextDidSave
```

**The one things that did work...**

When I change the predicate from `NSPredicate(format: "author = %@", user)` to `NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", 'My Title')` it will work as expected. Of course, this only works if for the one object with that title, but it will successfully save the context, merge changes, and update the collection as I would expect.

Comment: When you inspect the object that has been updated, what is the value of the `author` property?  If it is not the `Current.user`, the FRC will trigger a delete delegate call: since the object no longer matches the predicate, the corresponding collectionView cell must be deleted.

Comment: Yeah I thought of that too but after update the author object was still `Current.user`

Answer (score -2):

The problem is your **Predicate Format**. What you are trying to do is to find **Feed** objects for **current user** and you are writing it:-

```
NSPredicate(format: "author = %@", user)
```

**But it's a mistake**

Technically user is a Core-Data entry, but predicate doesn't validate directly with Core-Data entities. Predicate can validate with **Strings, Integers, Booleans, Date** type values.

So the solution is to modify your query to something like this:-

```
NSPredicate(format: "author.id = %@", user.id)
```

Where I'm assuming **id** is the primary key in your user table. So please be sure to replace **id** with your unique key which is in your user table. I hope this help.

Comment: `author` is a relationship with type NSManagedObject and is a valid query according to the documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html See the section `Using Joins` where it says "it is more efficient to test for object equality than to test for a property of the source object". Unfortunately, changing to `author.id = %@` did not work and caused a `libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`.